# PHP: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_contenthash() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have been getting the following error. Anyone, kindly assist.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT r.*
            FROM {plagiarism_moss_results} r
            LEFT JOIN {plagiarism_moss_matchedfiles} f ON r.id = f.result
            WHERE f.contenthash = :contenthash AND r.userid = :userid AND r.moss = :mossid ';
    if (!has_capability('plagiarism/moss:viewunconfirmed', get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $linkarray['cmid']))) {
        $sql .= 'AND r.confirmed = 1 ';
    }
    $sql .= 'ORDER BY r.rank ASC';
    $params = array(
        'userid'      => $linkarray['userid'],
        'contenthash' => $linkarray['file']->get_contenthash(),
        'mossid'      => $DB->get_field('plagiarism_moss', 'id', array('cmid' => $linkarray['cmid']))
    );
```

Comment: what is the value of `$linkarray['file']` ?

Comment: ok I saw your URL. http://csam.leadershipandsociety.org/moodle/mod/assign/view.php?id=4&action=grading Can you explain the process? or the error you are facing? also do you know the value of `$linkarray['file']`?

Comment: moodle is the elearning system in which you can create an assignment, the MOSS script is found in [link](https://moodle.org/plugins/view/plagiarism_moss). Although the main developer didnt particular tackle the issue before deploying. When you create an assignment, the MOSS engine has to be active. but I cant view results, it keep showing the above error I posted.

Comment: in your code, above the line with `$params` can you inert this: `var_dump($linkarray)` and tell me what results you see when you run the page.

Comment: 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$params' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/leaders1/public_html/csam/moodle/plagiarism/moss/lib.php on line 237'. That is the error I see

Comment: do yo have Teamviewer? maybe I can log in and see if I can help. its hard to do it through comments

Comment: Ok let me install Teamviewer, and can I write you via email?

Comment: Thank you Carlos, it worked...!

Answer (score 0):

Var_dump was added to the above code and it worked. Thank you @CodeGodie, he is a genius!

```
$sql = 'SELECT r.*
            FROM {plagiarism_moss_results} r
            LEFT JOIN {plagiarism_moss_matchedfiles} f ON r.id = f.result
            WHERE f.contenthash = :contenthash AND r.userid = :userid AND r.moss = :mossid ';
    if (!has_capability('plagiarism/moss:viewunconfirmed', get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $linkarray['cmid']))) {
        $sql .= 'AND r.confirmed = 1 ';
    }
    $sql .= 'ORDER BY r.rank ASC';
    var_dump($linkarray['file']->stored_file);
    $params = array(
        'userid'      => $linkarray['userid'],
        'contenthash' => "", // {$linkarray['file']}->get_contenthash(),
        'mossid'      => $DB->get_field('plagiarism_moss', 'id', array('cmid' => $linkarray['cmid']))
    );
```